# Shell script to copy multiple files

Tags: command-line, copy-and-paste

I'm trying to do a shell script that would copy a bunch of files but struggle with setting up a loop to read through the files:

```
aws s3 cp s3://noaa-bdp-pds/gdas.YYYYMMDD/00/atmos/hdas.t00z.sfcf000.nc s3://s3internal/raw/HDAS/hdas.YYYYMMDD_00Z.nc
```

Here YYYY, MM, DD are numbers that I need to loop through.

I need to loop through all years, all months, and then dates to save all files. Let me know if this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: Read `man seq`.

Comment: add all available combinations of YYYYMMDD to an array and use a for-loop to run the copy command for each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `aws s3 sync` with wildcard and `--dryrun` which produces the output:

```bsh
$ aws s3 sync s3://noaa-bdp-pds . \
  --exclude "*" --include "gdas.*/00/atmos/hdas.t00z.sfcf000.nc"

(dryrun) download s3://noaa-bdp-pds/gdas.20210001/00/atmos/hdas.t00z.sfcf000.nc to noaa-bdp-pds /gdas.20210001/00/atmos/hdas.t00z.sfcf000.nc
 ...
 ...
```

<sup>Remember to use an empty directory, or it may interfere with the output.</sup>

Now, you can use this to construct a loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for line in $( \
    aws s3 sync s3://noaa-bdp-pds . \
    --exclude "*" --include "gdas.*/00/atmos/hdas.t00z.sfcf000.nc" | awk '/s3:\/\//{print $3}' --dryrun \
); do
    [[ $line =~ .*/gdas.(.*)/00/.* ]] && \
    echo aws s3 cp ${BASH_REMATCH[0]} s3://s3internal/raw/HDAS/hdas.${BASH_REMATCH[1]}_00Z.nc
done
```

<sup>When you're satisfied with the result, remove `echo` to copy the files.</sup>

Comment: related: [AWS S3 ls wildcard support](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3784)